# How can I convert a wav blob to other audio types using javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, converters, wav, flac

I need to use either a FLAC or PCM audio type. Is there a library or an algorithm to convert to either of these?

Answer (score -1):

You can not do that using pure javascript. You will need at least an encoder with command line interface, and a server side script (like PHP) to access that and do the conversion.

(edit) I just found this link, I stand corrected if it really works: https://github.com/sopel39/audioconverter.js/tree/master